# Add Intent for a specific extension?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to set a particular extension for intent in the android studio.
`I have tried intent.setType("*\\.pdf")"`

Answer (score 1):

you have tried path to file (any path with pdf extension), thats not a `mimeType` which you should set in here. try to set proper value `intent.setType("application/pdf");`

```
Intent intentPdf = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intentPdf.setType("application/pdf");
intentPdf.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intentPdf, "Pick PDF"), CUSTOM_CODE_FOR_HANDLING_RESULT);
```

Comment: OK But can you also answer me if I want like intent for .xyz extension

Comment: afaik thats not possible, you can only define common filetypes by setting proper MIME type, some list in [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types). for all files you ma use `"*/*"` MIME type. also remember that this intent will be delivered to 3rd-party app, which may or may not respect your desired MIME type and may still show e.g. all files (always or when defined MIME type won't be resolved to an extension)

Comment: PS. you can try [THIS](https://github.com/nbsp-team/MaterialFilePicker) lib (and `withFilter` method) for picking file with desired extension, but be aware that this in fact custom `Activity`/`Dialog` opened inside your app, not `Intent` resolved by system with passing to another file picking app. you have to declare proper permissions by own

Comment: can you tell me the permissions

Comment: `"android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"` should be sufficient